# how can I implement the inAppSetting in myApp?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I added `InAppSettingsKit` in my project but the files are not being compiled, can someone please explain the  process of integrtating inAppSetting step-by-step?

```
#import"IASKAppSettingViewController.h"
```

This line is showing the error: `file not found.`

I tried to add it using Compile Sources but the InAppSetting folder is not being opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add the files to the target when you copy them.
You have to set a checkbox when dropping.

Now, you can go to Build Phases > Compile Sources > drop the files which aren't being compiled

Comment: can u please tell me the steps for integrating InAppSettingsKit....

Comment: I don't know InAppSettingsKit, but it sounds like you wouldn't have added it to the target. What is InAppSettingsKit? A framework or just some .h and .m files?

Comment: Googled it, just drop the files and make sure to check "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" and "Add to targets > yourtargetname"

Comment: yeah..it worked......thnxalot....